# Link formatting broken when it renders correctly in preview

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

I went back to an older answer of mine and I realized that the link formatting was broken (as you can see in [this revision](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/424591/4)):

[image]

But the preview (see—but don't save—[here](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/424591/edit/6c83b6d0-5308-45dc-955f-999082910d01)) showed that everything looked OK:

[image]

After a little bit of work, I figured out that it's the lack of a space before the double quote (the stuff in the quotes is supposed to be hover text).

I know that this broke pretty recently. Looking back at my answers, I think that it wasn't doing this as recently as [June 7th](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/449457/1). I know there's another change that was recently made as well that might be related: pasting links in the editor escapes `"`.

---

To demonstrate the problem, compare these:

```
[MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/"Solves none of your programming problems")
```

> [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/"Solves none of your programming problems")

```
[MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/" Solves none of your programming problems")
```

> [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/" Solves none of your programming problems")

```
[MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/ "Solves none of your programming problems")
```

> [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

They all render the same [in the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JibBt.png)...