# Question URL with quotes displays the actual question title during the edit preview, but not when the edit is saved

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview, internal-links

The Space SE question *[What have astronauts used rolls of Kapton tape for?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51722/12102)* originally [looks like this](https://space.stackexchange.com/revisions/51722/1) to me:

> [image: Displayed question]

Enclosing the URLs in quotes prevents the replacement of the URL with the actual question title during page display.

However, as soon as I clicked edit, the titles display properly, which is probably what led the OP to leave the quotes there:

> [image: editing preview of question]

Is this a feature, bug, something else?

Comment: Any difference between the preview and the rendered post is a bug.

Comment: @uhoh FYI, A quite similar problem, although I don't consider it close enough to be a duplicate, is [Link formatting broken when it renders correctly in preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311571/562482). Also, a somewhat related previous post is [Formatting problems with double quotes in URLs, mostly affecting the preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327769/562482).

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on MSO: [Why aren't quoted links consistently converted to hyperlinks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405377/4642212).

Comment: I think I've got a work-around now.  Angle brackets inside the double quotes: `"<https://___.stackexchange.com/q/___/___>"`  Still a bug, though.